# Не записываются задания в лист задач

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, localhost

есть лист задача на PHP + phpMyAdmin, по коду всё вроде правильно, не выбивает никакой ошибки, но не задания не добавляются в сам лист и БД. Вот код, в чём проблема?

```html
<?php 
 $errors = "";

 // подключение к БД
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mysql', 'todo');

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $task = $_POST['task'];
  if (empty($task)) {
   $errors = "Ты должен что-то записать";
  } else {
   mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tasks (task) VALUES ('$task')");
  header('location: index.php');
  }
 }

 // delete task
 if (isset($_GET['del_task'])) {
  $id = $_GET['del_task'];
  mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id=$id");
  header('location: index.php');
 }
 $tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Лист задач с PHPMyAdmin</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="heading">
  <h2>Лист задач используя MySQL</h2>
 </div>

 <form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <?php 
  if (isset($errors)) { ?>
   <p><?php echo $errors; ?></p>
  <?php } ?>
  <input type="text" name="task" class="task_input">
  <button type="submit" class="add_btn" name="submit">Добавить задание</button>
 </form>

 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>N</th>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <?php $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td class="task"><?php echo $row['task']; ?></td>
    <td class="delete">
     <a href="index.php?del_task=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">x</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  <?php $i++; } ?>
  </tbody>

 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="text" name="task" class="task_input">`

`name="tasks"` во множественном числе

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78056/discussion-on-answer-by-neo-new------).